# Launch app on using iOS 8 actionable notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, push-notification

In my application I have an actionable notification button. I want functionality such that when the notification is triggered and when you press the button the app should open and take you specific view controller.

I have tried this same functionality with simple notification ie notification without button it works fine as below method is called and app opens

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

but when I try to do with actionable notification ie pressing button below method is called but app remains in background

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

I have been trying very hard since few days but could find the solution.

Please help me....

Thanks

Comment: You can achieve this using payload in notification. You can retrieve payload in didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: When application is in background and if click actionable push notification button then handleActionWithIdentifier: forRemoteNotification: completionHandler method is called which does not open app the app remains in background  .If possible please provide demo code how this can be achived

Comment: When app open from push notification it always call didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: consider that if there are two different action on button and notification tap and when we tap button then didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called instead handleActionWithIdentifier : forRemoteNotification method is called which does not open app

Answer (score 2):

Set the `UserNotificationAction's` `activationMode` property to `UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground`

```
 notificationAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
```